# How can I cover or disguise gambrel-roofed shed, to better match my home style?

Tags: roof, shed

Can I disguise, cover or add a front “plate”, facing, or facade to make a gambrel-roofed shed better match a more traditional/conventional slant-roof home style? It’s too barn-y for the house, which is a 3-sides brick, 1960s mock Tudor.

Township ordinance states that if I move and replace it, I can’t keep it on the property line or keep the reinforced poured concrete slab it sits on, or keep the guttering and downspout on it, where it would end up having to be placed. If moved to code, it would end up almost touching my house on the garden/patio side where right now there are bushes, trees and distance which hide or disguise where it is now. You see it in full, face on, view when entering the rear entry drive now, though.

I’d like to keep this larger, 10 x 12 wooden shed with wide, double doors (but no windows or roof lights) right where it is—-but upgrade its exterior appearance. It has electricity abd water run to it, as the previous owner likely used it as a workshop and not fur storage as we do. A new shed of the same quality would likely cost about 8-12k. I’d like to do this upgrade for far less, as we plan to sell this home within 18-24 months.

Comment: Welcome to DiY! As you're partially asking about aesthetics, it would be very helpful if you could include some pictures of the building.

Comment: Should ask township if they consider roof changes/upgrades enough to cause problems.

Comment: Will depend on how much you want to change.  Imagine you could make a fake front so the old  roof line does not show from the road, or replace the roof to match the house.  A 10x12 is not that big of a roof to change.

Comment: The township stated that minor repair or upgrades don’t equal having to move or reconfigure the shed. Removing or replacing the shed roof entirely, would require significant changes to size and location of the upgraded outbuilding/any new building replacing it. 

So we’d like to alter in a minor way it’s aesthetics, without significantly replacing or rebuilding any part of it. 

We can replace or repair doors or roof with like for like, or paint it any color we want. We can add clerestory windows, skylights or eave windows to the existing front, back or side walls or roof.